# Ebay api call to change the order status "shipped"

Tags: ebay-api

Here, I am calling ebay api to change the order status "shipped".
I found some api call like, 
setshipmenttrackinginfo, setshipmentinfo etc.

Can anyone know what is the main api call to change the order status "shipped"?
Or is there one of them above two?

Answer (score 1):

I got answer for calling api to ebay to change the order status that is,
[CompleteSale](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/completesale.html#Request.Shipped)

Answer (score 0):

Using http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/CompleteSale.html#CompleteSale  API you can update status in eBay.

You can update status using **Shipped** tab & you can also update **feedback** using this API.

In this API you need only Auth Token & Item Id(Which is provide by eBay with Order)

Thanks,